# Perform action when any form input field has keyCode==13 (submit)

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a form field like this:

```
<form id="address_form">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="field_name">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="field_phone">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="field_email">
</form>
```

Right now, I am capturing an "enter" action with this:

```
$('#field_phone').keydown(function (e){
         if(e.keyCode == 13){
             alert("You pressed Enter");
         }
})
```

I don't want to do a function for every single field in the form. Is there a way to capture all fields in the `#address_form`?

Comment: Who not give them a class and do it for a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Simply match the `input[type=text]` and bind your event to that:

```js
$('#address_form input[type=text]').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("You pressed Enter");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="address_form">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="field_name">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="field_phone">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="field_email">
</form>
```

This example binds the `keydown` event to all the textboxes under the `#address_form`.

Answer (score 1):

Now all of input inside form is attached with this event

```
$('#address_form input').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        alert("You pressed Enter");
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="address_form">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="field_name" class="checkThis">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="field_phone" class="checkThis">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="field_email" class="checkThis">
</form>

<script>
$('.checkThis').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("You pressed Enter");
  }
})
</script>
```